Unable to get Power Delivery to work on Linux
Installed Arch Linux, and updated coreboot so it is hard to say which one is the culprit; I managed to rule out the charger itself because it does work with other devices.
> uname -r
6.9.7-arch1-1

> dmidecode -H 000
# dmidecode 3.5
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.3.0 present.
Table at 0x27F7CC000.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 26 bytes
BIOS Information
        Vendor: coreboot
        Version: 2023-10-13_5d997d1
        Release Date: 10/12/2023
        ROM Size: 16 MB
        Characteristics:
                PCI is supported
                PC Card (PCMCIA) is supported
                BIOS is upgradeable
                Selectable boot is supported
                ACPI is supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
        BIOS Revision: 4.19
        Firmware Revision: 0.0

My understanding is that I need two Kenel modules enabled, thunderbolt and typec both are to be loaded:
> lsmod | grep -E '(typec|thunderbolt)'
typec                 110592  1 intel_pmc_mux
thunderbolt           565248  0

I could not find any errors in dmesg or journalctl; only heads up that thunderbolt has been registered:
> journalctl -b | grep -E '(typec|thunderbolt)'
Jul 06 14:47:24 archlinux kernel: ACPI: bus type thunderbolt registered

One thing that surprised me is that lsusb -t does not list the Thunderbolt Controller:
> lsusb -t
/:  Bus 001.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
/:  Bus 002.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 003.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 001: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 007: Dev 003, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 007: Dev 003, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 010: Dev 004, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 010: Dev 004, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 004.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M

however lshw does find the controller:
> lshw -C bus

  *-usb:0
       description: USB controller
       product: Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: d
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
       resources: irq:127 memory:80760000-8076ffff
     *-usbhost:0
          product: xHCI Host Controller
          vendor: Linux 6.9.7-arch1-1 xhci-hcd
          physical id: 0
          bus info: usb@1
          logical name: usb1
          version: 6.09
          capabilities: usb-2.00
          configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
     *-usbhost:1
          product: xHCI Host Controller
          vendor: Linux 6.9.7-arch1-1 xhci-hcd
          physical id: 1
          bus info: usb@2
          logical name: usb2
          version: 6.09
          capabilities: usb-3.10
          configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=10000Mbit/s
  *-usb:1
       description: USB controller
       product: Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: d.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.2
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix usb4_host_interface bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=thunderbolt latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:80700000-8073ffff memory:8078d000-8078dfff
  *-usb:2
       description: USB controller
       product: Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
       resources: irq:135 memory:80770000-8077ffff
     *-usbhost:0
          product: xHCI Host Controller
          vendor: Linux 6.9.7-arch1-1 xhci-hcd
          physical id: 0
          bus info: usb@3
          logical name: usb3
          version: 6.09
          capabilities: usb-2.00
          configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
     *-usbhost:1
          product: xHCI Host Controller
          vendor: Linux 6.9.7-arch1-1 xhci-hcd
          physical id: 1
          bus info: usb@4
          logical name: usb4
          version: 6.09
          capabilities: usb-3.10
          configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=10000Mbit/s

My understanding is that controller should be visible on the file system at folder /sys/class/typec/port0 I do not see anything there:
> ls /sys/class/typec*
/sys/class/typec:

/sys/class/typec_mux:
CON0-mux  CON0-switch

Lastly, I tried running journactl -f and plugging in (to usb-c port ) flash drive and charger former shows logs, but later does not.
So I am at a loss. Hardware is detected, drivers are installed, what else is needed to make this work?
